# Запятая после "но не позднее пяти дней"

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после "неисправности"?

> В случае возникновения обстоятельств, указанных в пункте 4.6,
> Подрядчик вправе в разумный срок, но не позднее 5 (пяти) рабочих дней
> со дня обнаружения неисправности(,) направить Клиенту уведомление
> [...].

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна, чтобы закрыть оборот с уточнением, но "*в разумный срок*" (это нечто субъективное и образное) не подходит по стилю. Лучше так:
*В случае возникновения обстоятельств, указанных в пункте 4.6, Подрядчик вправе направить Клиенту уведомление, но не позднее 5 (пяти) рабочих дней со дня обнаружения неисправности.*

Comment: А то говорим о разумном сроке, а потом ограничиваем разумное. Это нелогично.